# compute true north based on successive user location

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm working on an app that should include a compass (it should work on iphone 3G also). however as there is no a compass on iphone 3G i'm looking for a way to know the true north orientation based on the CLLocation returned by the iPhone.

Note: the app should give as accurate as possible value even if the phone is using "cell towers" to know the actual position (not very accurate).

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't determine the orientation of the phone without a compass.  You can determine the direction of travel from successive locations.  Is that what you are asking?  How to compute the direction of travel?

Comment: Yes what i want is to determine the angle between thue north and the straight track segment between two point.

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate the users heading assuming they have been moving in a straight line between gps updates.

I would first set the desired accuracy to the highest.  You will need it since a small change in position will result in a large change in angle.

Now call the coordinate of the first location `L1`, and the coordinate of the next location `L2`.

Your heading vector , `h` = `L2 - L1`

now if `h = (lon, lat)`

To get the heading you need use some trig:

`x = arctan ( lon / lat )`

I would consider taking averages / smoothing the result somehow.